# Is it a good practice to have just a single form?

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns

I'm essentially a web developer, but I want to know if it is a good practice to have one main form in desktop applications (winforms), I mean for log in form, main form, help form,... just by rendering/removing controls inside a single form? or it is better to have a new form for each one?

Comment: you need to have a seperate form for each. you cannot include in the same form

Comment: Well, you can. But you shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise against it. It would be a nightmare to maintain all of that state.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally better to have a form for each one, mainly for ease of maintenance but it can also help with the overall design of the application. E.g., if the Login is a dedicated form, you can reuse that Login dialog anywhere in the application if you wanted to, say if the user timed out after signing in.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use seperate forms individually for each and it is completely based on how you design your application